# How to remove icon-seperator in Material UI : DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI Data Grid, I tried searching on web on How to remove icon-separator in material UI DataGrid but couldn't find any references. How can we remove it, I don't want them in my table header

[image: material]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply this style to the header

```css
'& > .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator': {
    visibility: 'hidden',
},
```

Comment: how do you apply this to the header?

Comment: @Hola
<DataGrid
     sx={{
       '& > .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator': {
            visibility: 'hidden',
        }
    }}
/>